# Wierd project context menu with TeXlipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tex

I just installed TeXlipse 1.5.0 on Eclipse Kepler and the project context menu seems really weird:

[image]

This only happens with the TeXlipse perspective, in all other perspectives the context menu has the expected entries.

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/eclipse/texlipse/issues

Comment: @torkildr I used Kepler only briefly because of this bug. I am not sure it will be helpful to report a bug on a software I no longer use.